# Hide field using group

Tags: python, xml, odoo-12

I want to hide the field for some users who are not in the group.
Field: phone, module: res_partner

For this, I overridden the field by adding a group:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    phone = fields.Char(groups='cmz_security_contacts.field_invisible_from_contacts')
```

Created groups:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="0">
         <record id="group_contact_user" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">User</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_contacts"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        </record>

        <record id="group_contact_manager" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Manager</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_contacts"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_contact_user'))]"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
        </record>

        <record id="field_invisible_from_contacts" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Field invisible from contacts</field>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

"Normal" user with rights "Users". When I click some contact: Error: "Unknown field phone in domain" Why?

***Edit:***

- Inheriting the `sms.partner_form_send_sms_form_view`

  ```
    <odoo>
        <record id="partner_form_send_sms_form_view_secure" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.form.send.sms.secure</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sms.partner_form_send_sms_form_view"/>
            <field name="priority">10</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//button[@name=%(sms.send_sms_form_action)d]" position="attributes">
                       <attribute name="groups">cmz_security_contacts.field_invisible_from_contacts</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </odoo>
  ```
- Overriding `phone` and `mobile` fields to set `groups` attribute

  ```
    from odoo import api, fields, models

    class Partner(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'res.partner'

        phone = fields.Char(groups='cmz_security_contacts.field_invisible_from_contacts')
        mobile = fields.Char(groups='cmz_security_contacts.field_invisible_from_contacts')
  ```

How to locate the `mobile` button in `partner_form_send_sms_form_view`?

Comment: How you used the ``phone`` field in the views?

Comment: Kenly, This is described in base>views>res_partner_views

Comment: So the error did not come from your XML definition, the problem is in the field access. Check my answer below (the commend was too long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you did not use the phone field in a domain.

Many views are inheriting the partner view, the `sms.partner_form_send_sms_form_view` view adds a button (`Send SMS`) which uses the phone field in attrs (`attrs="{'invisible':[('phone', '=', False)]}"`).

Even if you change that, there is an error (`TypeError: dict.record.phone is undefined`) in the kanban view which checks for `phone` field value (`t-if="record.phone.raw_value">`), but you can simply avoid that by checking if the phone field exists before trying to get its value.

You need to update the partner view according to your changes because you restricted the field access to the users of the given groups only.

Comment: Kenly, I.e, where this field is used, I must check if the user has the right?

Comment: Yes, you need to change that code. Your question title says `Hide field using group` but the `groups` attribute is used to restrict the field access to the users of the given groups only. If you need to use the groups attribute you will need to change the code depending on the phone field, for example in the SMS module the button `Send SMS` is shown when the value of the phone field is set so try to restrict access to that button by using groups on the parent div.

Comment: Kenly,  This works for the "phone"  field,  but for the "mobile" field there is no :((

Comment: You need to restrict access to the mobile field too?

Comment: Yes, check my answer below.

Comment: Rights were established for one button only, I think..

Comment: You need to make the same changes with the mobile field.

Comment: You added an answer, so it wokks.

Comment: But for these two fields the button is the same. What should I write here?

Comment: <xpath expr="//????]" position="attributes">
                   <attribute name="groups">cmz_security_contacts.field_invisible_from_contacts</attribute>
            </xpath>

Comment: You can use `//div[@class='o_row'][2]/button` expression to select the second button.

Answer (score 0):

Kenly, I want hide 'email':

```
email = fields.Char(groups='cmz_security_contacts.field_invisible_from_contacts')
```

But when I choose a contact:
The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: Contact, Operation: read) - (User: 125, Fields: email)
Why am I getting this message if the limit is set only on a field?
Why I didn't get it for fields phone and mobile ?
Thx.

Comment: If this is part of your question, you have just to edit it and add more details if not ask a new question. I was not notified and to notify me using my name you need to add `@` at the beginning. You should remove this answer and edit you question above or ask a new one.